# Serialize a interface type variable to string

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and trying to serialize my response of interface type into string to store them in session storage. But they are getting stored as [object] into the session storage

My code is as below:

```
  const loginResponse = await this.serverLoginSvc.login(this.serverData);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(loginResponse.data));
  sessionStorage.setItem('source_auth_data', JSON.stringify(loginResponse.data));
```

where `loginResponse` is of type `ApiResponseModel<AuthResponseModel>` interface

please help me identify what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Try check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for more info related to sessionStorage.

However it's better to avoid async storage settings related to the login without the control of the response.

For your solution i can suggest you this library that use localStorage and indexedDB: [local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage)

With something like this:

```
this.serverLoginSvc.login(this.serverData).subscribe(
  next: (response: ApiResponseModel<AuthResponseModel>) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response !== undefined && response !== null) {
      this.storage.set('source_auth_data', response.data).subscribe(() => {
        // Do something
      });
    }
  },
  error: error => {
    this.storage.delete('source_auth_data');
  }
);
```

Note: login should return an Observable.